# Twilio - How to proper return activities on encoding ISO-8859-1?

Tags: twilio

I'm facing a problem to work with activities that uses accents (diacritics). If I create an Activity like "Consolação", when I call the function to fill my activities array, the returns shows me something like:

```
{ ... //many attributes
  "friendlyName": "Concei??o",
  ...
}
```

This is how I get all my activities:

```
worker = new Twilio.TaskRouter.Worker(workerToken)
function loadActivitySids() {
  worker.activities.fetch(function(error, activityList) {
    if ( error ) {
      console.log(error.message);
      return;
    }
    var activities = activityList.data;
    activities.forEach(function(activity) {
      activitySids[activity.friendlyName] = activity.sid;
    });
  });
}
```

Is there anyway that allow me create activities using accents?

Comment: How are you setting the activity name?

Comment: On Twilio console. Just wrote "Conceição"

Comment: Is that loading the activities via the client side JavaScript?